# TCP advertised window in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: networking, window, resize, google, proc

I want to increase TCP advertised window beyond 10 packets. I have tried tweaking most of the relevant parameters in /proc/sys/net/ like

`/proc/sys/net/core/rmem_max,
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_rmem`

I wanted to test the paper by google "Increasing the initial congestion window". I am able to test it till the congestion window on the server side is increased till 10. But after that it keeps waiting for an ack from the client (my ubuntu box) because the advertised window is close to 10 packets.

All other settings are default as in ubuntu 11.10 (tcp cubic reno)

Am i doing something wrong. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the receive window size on the client needs to be set per route table entry, e.g.

```
ip route change default via 1.2.3.4 initrwnd 16
```

(use your actual default route of course)

TCP will only send using the lower of the two values (initrwnd on the client, initcwnd on the server).